# I am trying to take data using VBA and paste it into a cell in a different sheet

Tags: excel, vba

My question is that I'm trying to use Excel VBA and select a specific name in a column and then take the data from a cell to right of it and place this data into a cell in a different sheet

```
Sub button()

a = Worksheets("three").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Dim lastrow As Long, errow As Long
If Worksheets("three").Range("G1") = "email@domain.com" Then
    Worksheets("three").Range("G1").Offset(i, 1).Copy
    Worksheets("three").Activate
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("c3")
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to add in your question what specifically is not happening correctly with your VBA code. You shouldn't expect us to guess.

Comment: You are looking for .Offset(i, 1), but you never defined the variable i.  Also, you have two .activates is a row, the first one isn't affecting anything.   Also you should not use activesheet, instead use the workbook directly, like you do in assigning a value to variable a.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is probably not quite as simple what you are trying to achieve, but for starters, this is how you would do it for 1 record, as per your code:

```vb
Sub button()

With Worksheets("three").Range("G1")
    If .Value = "email@domain.com" Then
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C3") = .Offset(0, 1).Value
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much that was great, but how would i extend the with statement if i have a second data two cells to the right

Comment: Also im searching not by cell but by the entire column. I tried Range("G1:G") but it didnt work.

Comment: do you think I should put in an active workbook since my data is going to be constantly updated